# How to loop over shell arguments in reverse order?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I want to build a loop in my shell script where i run over all arguments in reverse order and use them in a command. How can this be done?

My specific code would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
for MODULE in "$@"
do
rmmod $MODULE
done
for MODULE in "$@"
do
insmod $MODULE
done
dmesg -c
```

but i want the "insmod" in the second for-loop to be called with the arguments from last to first instead.

Comment: Do you *need* to use `#!/bin/sh`, or are you assuming that you'll be using `bash`?

Comment: The simplest solution is to build an array in reverse order while traversing `"$@"`, or to use a C-style `for` loop, but `/bin/sh` doesn't necessarily support either.

Comment: How can i check what i have available? If I do `echo $SHELL` on the device i want to run this, i get `/bin/sh` as answer

Comment: If `/bin/bash` exists you can (and should) use it in scripts by changing the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`. Then you get access to many more features.

Comment: `/bin/bash` does not exist, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're targeting plain `sh` and not `bash` then you won't have any array features to speak of. You could use a recursive function:

```
#!/bin/sh

resetmods() {
    rmmod "$1"
    [ "$#" -gt 1 ] && (shift; resetmods "$@")
    insmod "$1"
}

resetmods "$@"
dmesg -c
```